# Images are not getting uploaded

Tags: images, uploads, media-library

I have an wordpress installation, which worked fine up until recently. I somehow can't upload any images. They won't show up on the server, and when I upload the manually via FTP wordpress ignores them and acts as if they are not there.
I already tried a few different solutions I found on the web, like adjusting the permissions, but it doesn't seem to work.
But the image is uploaded somewhere, because when I click on edit Picture it shows it. Although the src of the image is some temporary folder.

The debug mode also shows nothing. No errors.

**EDIT 1:**
I downloaded a fresh wordpress ZIP and replaced all the files in the FTP with the ones in the ZIP, except for the wp-content folder and wp-config.php

Still not working

**EDIT 2:**
This is the src part of the img tag in the image edit screen: `src="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=imgedit-preview&_ajax_nonce=3020365e3a&postid=258&rand=12762"`

Comment: Can you post one of those URLs with the temporary folder in it? If you haven´t modified your WordPress, all uploads should go to `/wp-content/uploads/`

Comment: Oh, and can you upload images via the Media library? Any error messages, when uploading images that way?

Comment: @flomei I updated my question with the src part of the img tag.
I only upload images via media library, it's not working either. It also doesn't show any kind of error. Not even in the server log.